# How to filter groups that have at least 1 member in Graph API?

Tags: http, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of all groups in a tenant, but only groups that actually have members are relevant to me. The documentation ([use of $count in $filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#query-scenarios-that-require-advanced-query-capabilities)) ([supported objects in advanced queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#microsoft-graph-objects-that-support-advanced-query-capabilities)) seems to vaguely imply i can filter based on members of a group. however, the query gives me an error.

This is the query i tried

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=members/$count ge 1
```

however, this gives me the following error:

```json
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Property 'members' does not exist as a declared property or extension property."
    }
```

Is there any way i can do this with a filter? or do i have to check with a seperate request for every group if it has members?

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: @RaytheonXie-MSFT it looks like filtering like this is currently not possible. i've resorted to just filtering based on other conditions. or making multiple requests where needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AFAIK, there is no direct **filter** to retrieve groups having at least 1 member.

When I ran your query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I too got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=members/$count ge 1
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below Python code by formatting the `/groups` response to retrieve groups having at least 1 member:

```py
import requests

access_token = "token"
groups_api_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
}

response = requests.get(groups_api_url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    groups = response.json().get("value", [])

    for group in groups:
        group_id = group['id']
        members_api_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members"
        members_response = requests.get(members_api_url, headers=headers)

        if members_response.status_code == 200 and members_response.json().get("value", []):
            print(f"Group ID: {group_id}, Group Name: {group['displayName']} has at least one member")
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

**Response:**

[image]